# How to use python program for a web extension?

Tags: javascript, python

I am making a simple web extension. I want to attach a python program to its files so that the python program can use the data entered by the user in the extension popup for a particular operation and the output will be displayed on the extension popup.

Please guide me in this process. It's my first time making a web extension.

Comment: I don't think you can use pythin in a web browser extension .... yet (or can you point to documentation that says otherwise) I do recall reading something about pythin coming to the browser - but that may have been on April 1

Comment: You cannot run python code in the context of a browser extension. You need to send the data to your server, process it using Python, then send back a reply. Your extension can now display the reply. Or you port the python code to JS.

Comment: https://www.anaconda.com/blog/pyscript-python-in-the-browser and https://realpython.com/brython-python-in-browser/ suggest Pythin can be run in the browser

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can execute python script inside javascript file.
these are two option you can use:-

1. create api with python script and call api inside you javascript file.
2. explore [pyscript](https://pyscript.net/) , Pyscript is used for using python script inside html code.(I have not tried it yet)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PyScript](https://alexplesoiu.medium.com/pyscript-a-new-way-of-building-html-websites-tutorial-for-beginners-67a75935e039) to write your entire extension with Python.

Take a look at this simple example of running python and DOM manipulating:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />
        <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>
         <style>
            h1 {
                font-size: 20px; 
                color: green; 
                text-transform: uppercase;
                text-align: center; 
                margin: 0 0 35px 0; 
                text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #f2f2f2;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>PyScript Events</h1>
    <div>
        <p> I am just a random element </p>
        <p id="change_me"> I think PyScript is awesome </p>
        <p> I like hamburgers  </p>
    </div>
    
    <py-script>
import pyodide

def on_click(e):
    e.target.innerHTML = "PyScript is really awesome!"
    
change_me_element = document.getElementById('change_me')
change_me_element.addEventListener('click', pyodide.create_proxy(on_click))
    </py-script>
    
    </body>
```

[Here](https://alexplesoiu.medium.com/pyscript-a-new-way-of-building-html-websites-tutorial-for-beginners-67a75935e039) you have a great tutorial about getting started with PyScript.